# How to remove the transition from GatsbyImages

Tags: gatsby

I have a bunch of images which I'd like to remove the "fade in" transition from since they load fairly quickly being loaded into the page at build time.  I've tried

- using `placeholder: NONE` in my graphql queries and `loading="eager"` in the React markup
- setting `transition: none` on both the `style` prop and in css under a `.gatsby-image-wrapper` selector

Neither has worked consistently.  Is there a consistent way to remove this fade in?  I'm okay with the images just appearing if they don't load fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried is what I'd suggest. The CSS selector should do the trick:

```
.gatsby-image-wrapper [data-main-image]
```

Plus playing around with the `opacity` + `transition` rule to override the default's one.

However, it may slightly change depending on the scenario so it may not work 100% of the time. There's no built-in way beyond what you've tried so far.

I think it will be easier to use the standard `img` tag using the `lazy` property which is pretty standardized nowadays: https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr by getting rid of `GatsbyImage` component.

Comment: Getting rid of the GatsbyImage component isn't great since I like the other optimization tricks GatsbyImage does in the build step.  I think I was missing the `[data-main-image]` part of the selector

Comment: If getting rid of `GatsbyImage` is not a solution for your scenario, give it a try to the CSS (pseudo)selector and come back with the output :)

Answer (score 1):

The GatsbyImage component has a [imgStyle prop](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#shared-props) that lets you override a single image *fade in* transition.
I'm using this for specific images that wont have proper placeholders while avoiding setting something global:

```
<GatsbyImage
  image={image}
  imgStyle={{ transition: 'none' }}
/>
```